# How do I use the recently introduced i18n capability of Angular2 with an angular-cli generated webpack project

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization, webpack, angular-cli

We've been awaiting the official implementation of **i18n** from the **Angular2** team for some time. Now that it is available I'm not completely sure I understand the optimum way in which it should be implemented. There seem to be a number of variations on a theme, some of which seem very obvious and neat, but none of which provides the complete story for **Angular2 + angular-cli + webpack**.

Like many other international projects, we want to be able to work with a set of **xliff** files that our translators would provide (***.xlf**). I expect the webpack build to provide all of the language files somewhere appropriate and the Angular2 implementation to load all of them at runtime. Depending upon which language the user requires, as indicated by their browser language selection, the correct bundle of translated strings would be applied to the application templates. If the user changes their language preference a page refresh would be sufficient to change the bundle used. If there is no bundle available for a specified language, the application would fall back to another bundle automatically.

The official documentation for this feature is available here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html

I'm not too worried about the auto-generation features for the xliff files (**ng-xi18n**). We just need to know where to put the xliff files in the directory structure, where they should end up in a (**angular-cli**) built **webpack** project, and what components are required to read and load them. Finally is there anything else that is required to allow an **i18n** pipe to be placed on an html element and the appropriate translation used?

Comment: As of `angular-cli v1.0.0-beta.19`, it seems to be no final version of `i18n` handling. There is a discussion/issue on the `angular-cli` GitHub related to the `i18n` - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2201.